# Contacts and relationships' report

Tags: relationships

I want to report/view which shows me all contacts in a group, and any relationships they may have.
I’ve used the relationships report, but it doesn’t show me everyone in the group. It doesn’t show me those who DONT have any relationships.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SearchKit:

- Search for: Contacts
- With (optional): Related Contacts
- Where: In Groups: Name of your group

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go.